# MonoDevelop gdb debugger on Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, gdb, monodevelop, d

Sorry for my English.
I start to learn D programming language. The only fine IDE is MonoDevelop (mono-d plug-in), but on I can't understand how to integrate MonoDevelop with GDB (from MinGW) on Windows?

There is way on linux: download from git repository and type:
./configure --select
In menu we can select necessary components (monodevelop-gdb-debugger in this case).

But I don't know, how to build monodevelop sources on Windows. I don't know already builded plug-in for this purposes.

What can I do? :(

Comment: There is also very nice Visual-D for Windows (i presume you use Windows, why else would you use MinGW :). I think MonoDevelop can't use GDB on Windows.

Comment: Visual-D even doesn't have fine intellisense support.

Comment: You probably expected this answer, but I will say it anyway - both are opensource projects, so - get the code - implement missing feature, and send it to the author... :) Anyway, MonoDevelop uses GDB temporarily (untili MonoDebug is ready). Visual-D's intellisense is improving rapidly. Finally, nothing prevents you to invoke GDB manually, and do the debugging, right? :) I think it is possible to use external GDB frontend like DDD from MonoDevelop, problem is - I know now GDB frontend for Windows...

Comment: >implement missing feature, and send it to the author
I don't know D. I'm only beginner and want fine IDE for language learning.

>nothing prevents you to invoke GDB manually, and do the debugging, right
Probably :) But I didn't use GDB manually. Please, give a link, how to attach GDB manually to my program?

What will I able to use? Breakpoints? Variables values? etc.

Comment: MonoDevelop and Mono-D are both done in C#. I have already mentioned one GDB GUI frontend - DDD, here is another one: http://www.affinic.com/?page_id=109